# How do I lean a xul element to the right side of a variably sized centered element?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

<sup><edit>I decided to clean this question up a little bit, for easier reading.</edit></sup>

I have a centered `<menulist>`, of variable width (`maxwidth="200"`), next to which I want to lean a couple of `<toolbarbuttons>` in an `<hbox>`. These elements are part of a xul `<page>` element.

The following image shows what my current result is and what my actual goal is:

[image: Current result and goal]

<sup>The vertical red line is merely drawn to indicate the center of the window.</sup>

The current result was achieved with the following css and xul:

**css:**

```
page {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

toolbarbutton {
  list-style-image: url( 'chrome://codifiertest/skin/icons.png' );
}
toolbarbutton .toolbarbutton-icon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

toolbarbutton.add {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 16px, 16px, 0px );
}

toolbarbutton.edit {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 32px, 16px, 16px );
}

toolbarbutton.delete {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 48px, 16px, 32px );
}

toolbarbutton.config {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 64px, 16px, 48px );
}
```

**xul:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://codifiertest/skin/index.css"?>

<!DOCTYPE page>

<page xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
      xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
      xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <h1>Title</h1>

    <vbox xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
          pack="start"
          align="center">

      <stack maxwidth="200">
        <hbox pack="center" align="center">
          <menulist maxwidth="200">
            <menupopup>
              <menuitem label="Item" value=""/>
            </menupopup>
          </menulist>
        </hbox>
        <hbox left="200">
          <toolbarbutton class="add"/>
          <toolbarbutton class="edit"/>
          <toolbarbutton class="delete"/>
        </hbox>
      </stack>

    </vbox>

  </div>

</page>
```

**icons.png:**

[image: The used icons]

---

<sup>You can also download this as an installable bootstrapped test example:</sup>

<sup>http://extensions.codifier.nl/test/downloads/test@extensions.codifier.nl.xpi</sup>

<sup>Be aware that the example xpi install will immediately open a new tab with the example xul file after install. And as a **disclaimer**: the file is downloadable from an insecure location (my own domain), so be sure you validate what you downloaded before you install (i.e. save the xpi to disk first, before installing).</sup>

---

So, the goal is to always have the `<menulist>` horizontally centered to the page and the `<hbox>` with `<toolbarbutton>`s lean to right side of the `<menulist>`, no matter its width.

Is this doable with xul and perhaps some additional css?

I've actually gotten it to work by mixing in more (x)html:

**css:**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

**altered xul/(x)html:**

```
<html:div id="container"> <!-- no more xul:stack -->
  <hbox pack="center" align="center">
    <menulist maxwidth="200">
      <menupopup>
        <menuitem label="Item" value=""/>
      </menupopup>
    </menulist>
  </hbox>
  <html:span> <!-- additional span -->
    <hbox>
      <toolbarbutton class="add"/>
      <toolbarbutton class="edit"/>
      <toolbarbutton class="delete"/>
    </hbox>
  </html:span>
</html:div>
```

... but I'd really rather want to see a pure xul solution though, if anyone knows one.

Thank you, in advance, for looking into this.

Comment: You might be able to add some CSS to text-align it properly. Please see if you could replicate in JSFiddle and post the link.

Comment: @WebDev As far as I'm aware, xul is not replicable in jsfiddle. Although it has similarities, xul is a different beast than your regular (x)html. In (x)html my problem would be a no-brainer. But since I'm already mixing (x)html with this xul document, you have actually given me the idea to try it with wrapping the xul elements in (x)html elements. So thank you for that. I'll report back with the results later on.

Comment: @WebDev It actually worked! :-) I would still be open to see a pure xul solution though, if anyone knows one.

Comment: glad to hear I could be of help. I also would be interested in hearing if there is a xul solution. I'll keep my eye out.

Comment: I tried your original code in both XUL Explorer and as a stand alone XUL file opened in a tab in Firefox. In neither instance did it render as depicted in your image. It would be helpful if you could provide the associated CSS code that you are using so that we can have a known starting point to work from rather than have to first modify the code you have provided just to get it to display close to what your image shows the current code displays. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Makyen My apologies: I've added a more thorough and accurate example now. You can even download a test xpi now. Thank you for looking in to this.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the HTML element/CSS solution you developed? BTW: That should be an answer, not part of the question. Please put it in as an answer.

Comment: BTW: Using `maxwidth="200"` on both the `<stack>` and the `<menulist>` should result in no room available for the buttons if the `<menulist>` grows too big.  However, the `maxwidth="200"` on the `<stack>` does not appear to be obeyed. If you really want the `<stack>` to be width limited to 200, you will need to define the  `maxwidth` on the `<menulist>` to your desired maximum width minus the width you determine for the `<toolbarbutton>`'s `<hox>` (and any space between such and the `<menulist>`.

Comment: I would suggest changing the `<menulist>` and `<toolbarbutton class="add"/>` to something like `<menulist maxwidth="200" id="theMenulist">` and `<toolbarbutton class="add" oncommand="document.getElementById('theMenulist').appendItem('Item 2 much much much much much longer','','');" />`. Doing so will provide a test case (click `+` button) for both the desired variable nature of the `<menulist>` and the `maxwidth="200"` (which is not obeyed on the `<stack>` element. Note that this would demonstrate that your original code could result in the `<menulist>` and `<toolbarbutton>`s overlapping.

Comment: The overlap occurs because the `<stack>` element remains symmetric around the center of the page. In other words, it includes a considerable amount of empty space to the left of the left edge of the `<menulist>`. Thus, using `left="200"` on the `<toolboxbutton>`s' `<hbox>` does not work as you are expecting. You can use [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) to see what is happening.

Comment: Based on information from Ondřej Doněk's xpi: All you have to do to make the original code work is change: `<hbox left="200">` to `<hbox right="-66">`.  I'll remove this comment if he updates his answer, as the information really came from him, but is not in his answer.

Comment: @Makyen Right, I think the `maxwidth="200"` on the `<stack>` may have gotten in there by mistake. But the negative value for the `right` attribute on the `<hbox>` seems to work indeed! Since I know the total width of the `<hbox>` this is no problem. So that's great. Thank you and Ondřej Doněk for looking in to this and coming up with an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be the solution:

**page.xul**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="page.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE page>
<page xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
      xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
      xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <vbox>
        <hbox>
            <hbox>
                <menulist>
                    <menupopup>
                        <menuitem label="Item" value=""/>
                    </menupopup>
                </menulist>
            </hbox>
            <hbox>
                <button class="add"/>
                <button class="edit"/>
                <button class="delete"/>
            </hbox>
        </hbox>
        <hbox>
            <hbox>
                <menulist>
                    <menupopup>
                        <menuitem label="Item" value=""/>
                    </menupopup>
                </menulist>
            </hbox>
            <hbox>
                <button class="add"/>
                <button class="edit"/>
                <button class="delete"/>
            </hbox>
        </hbox>
    </vbox>
</page>
```

**page.css:**

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
page {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url( 'dot.png' );
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
page > vbox {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
}
page > vbox {
    padding-left: 90px;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
}
.buttonsgroup {
    -moz-appearance: toolbox;
}
button {
    -moz-appearance: toolbarbutton;
    list-style-image: url( 'icons.png' );
    min-width: 27px !important; 
    width: 27px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
button.add {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 16px, 16px, 0px );
}
button.edit {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 32px, 16px, 16px );
}
button.delete {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 48px, 16px, 32px );
}
button.config {
  -moz-image-region: rect( 0px, 64px, 16px, 48px );
}
```

Here is how it looks (on FF 36, Kubuntu 15.04):

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm afraid you have misunderstood my requirements: the `<menulist>` must always stay dead centered, not the `<hbox>` with `<menulist>` and `<button>`s.

Comment: I updated CSS - is still not perfect - and need some css work around the buttons... but left padding on the first inner `<vbox>` is what you need. See picture - is also updated - the red line is just 1px background image to see where the center of page is.

Comment: Currently the padding is 90px which is not correct but with some effort you will polish this.

Comment: I don't have time to look very close into this now, but since the bounty would expire within the hour, I figured I might as well award it to you, for your effort, since the bounty would be lost otherwise anyway, I believe. But, at first glance I think this will still not work entirely as I'd hoped. However, I'll come back with a more researched reply, when I have fiddled with it. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: On win7 FF36.0.4 The `<menulist>` initially displays only `...`, not `Item`. If the `label` is changed the displayed text is truncated. This is significantly different than the original and the HTML/CSS solution in the question which do not truncate unless the `label` becomes longer than would fit in `200` pixels, as defined in `maxwidth="200"`. Adding `maxwidth="200"` to the `<menulist>` elements does not solve this issue.

Comment: I suggest to look inside FF source codes - their CSS is like a magic inside these elements... and of course is different for each supported platform.

Comment: That truncated text - it's because that 200px width - that is obvious - so adding 200px not SOLVE the issue but it CREATES that issue :).

Comment: I customized your XPI (just slight change to your original code) - you can find it here: http://jmp.sh/cEZgMO8 --- but I must say, that your original code is pretty messy in way how are XHTML and XUL mixed and I would never write this in this style by my own :) ...

Comment: No, it is not the 200px limit (which does not exist in your code above). The total width of the `<menulist>` continues to increase as the `label` length is increased. It just truncates display of the label text. For example `Item` results in `...`; `Item 1` results in `It...`; `Item 2 longer` results in `Item 2 l...`; etc.

Comment: Ok, I have no access to Windows right now but can you test XPI which I send above?

Comment: The XPI which I downloaded from the link above works correctly.  However, it is significantly different than the code in this answer.

Comment: Yes, that is true and I wrote that above. But thanks for testing it.

Comment: @OndřejDoněk Thank you (and Makyen) for looking into this! Your downloadable xpi works the way I intended. The negative value for the `right` attribute did the trick. And since I know the total width of the `<hbox>` containing the buttons, using a absolute value is no problem. So thanks again for a working solution!

Comment: @OndřejDoněk PS.: About the messy xhtml and xul mix: I agree. This add-on is still in its early developing stages. I'm just trying things out. And since I want to minimize the use of xhtml I definitely wanted a solution for *this* problem in xul. So, thanks again!

Comment: @Codifier - you can think through about using GitHub and collaborators :) Have a nice day, glad to help.

Comment: Please update this answer to reflect the code in the `.xpi` you made available for download.  The changes needed are much simpler than are included in this answer, and the answer does not work in all operating systems.  It would be much better if the accepted answer reflects the simple solution of using a negative number for `right=`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an answer that states the actual solution to the problem rather than it only being in the comments.  This answer is based on information from Ondřej Doněk's `.xpi` which was placed as downloadable in a comment to [the answer that user provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29528649/3773011).

**The easy solution:**
All you have to do to make the original code work is change:

```
<hbox left="200">
```

to

```
<hbox right="-66">
```

MDN says that for elements immediately within XUL [`<stack>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/stack) elements, the attribute [`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/right):

> specifies the pixel position of the right edge of the element relative
>   to the right edge of the stack.

Based on the fact that using a negative number such as `right="-66"` works, we can deduce that what it is actually telling the stack to do is: enlarge such that the right edge of the `<stack>` is 66 pixels to the right of where it was and place the element with its right edge at the right edge of the stack.

If Ondřej Doněk's answer is updated to include information about using a negative number for the `right` attribute, then this community wiki answer can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS looks good. You can solve this with pure attributes of XUL. You can use: `pack, orient, align, flex ...`

Try play with the xul-periodic-table example:

https://github.com/alijc/xul-periodic-table/blob/master/layout.xul

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've exhausted these options already. I would really rather like to see a definite working example with the requirements I've put forward.